# Request for improvement. Isn't it too much variables?

Tags: python

I'm learning and looking for at least "not bad" quality of my code. Please let me know how should I improve.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import re

battery_status = subprocess.run('upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0 | grep percentage:',
    shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)

b_strip = re.sub(r"\t\n\s\W", " ", battery_status.stdout)
b_join = "".join([i for i in b_strip if i not in [' ', '%', '\t', '\n']])
b_split = b_join.split(':')
b_result = int(b_split[1])

if b_result >= 30:
    print("Safe to work. You have", b_result, "%", "charge left")
else:
    print("Please save. You have", b_result, "%", "charge left")
```

Comment: This is text parsing code. I suspect you'll increase your chance of getting useful feedback if you show people **the text** – ie,  an example output of the relevant `upower` command.

Comment: @BansheePrime Welcome to CR! Please pick a title that describes what the script does. We know you're here because you have a request for improvement; if we all used generic titles like that, it'd be impossible to find anything. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. I think it would be very helpful for you to read our [help section](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), especially [How do I ask a good question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). As @ggorlen pointed out the title needs some work. If your title followed the guidelines better I think you would have scored some up votes on this question.

Comment: At this moment, there is still no description in either title or question body as to what this code is supposed to do. Please try to follow the helpful advice you've been provided for your next question.

Answer (score 6):

### Security

Using `shell=True` has **security** implications (shell injection) which are mentioned in the Python doc: [subprocess — Subprocess management: security considerations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations). So this parameter should be avoided unless truly needed and third-party input must be sanitized always.

While it assumed you are running a controlled environment, you have no control over the output format of cli utilities. It could change in the future.

See also this discussion: [Actual meaning of 'shell=True' in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3172470) and also [Security implications of Suprocess executing with a active shell vs no shell](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/162938/125626)

### Simplify the parsing

I think the current implementation of parsing stdout is overkill.

Indeed, some **error handling** is required. But since you are already doing regexes you could perhaps apply a formula to the whole stdout output and look for the line that contains "percentage", followed by whitespace and a numeric value and the % sign. You are expecting to find one line.

Example:

```
import re
match = re.search("percentage:\s*([0-9]+)%", stdout, re.MULTILINE)
if match:
    percentage = match.group(1)
    print(f"Percentage: {percentage}")
else:
    print("Percentage value not found !")
```

There is no need for splitting etc. A regex is sufficient to address your need.

NB: I don't know if upower returns decimals, then you may have to adjust the regex.

### Check the return code

One bonus: check the return code of your call. The command may fail for various reasons, also when running a command that is not present on the target system. All you need is to add this:

```
print(f"returncode: {battery_status.returncode}")
```

0  = OK, 1 = failure

So check the return code before you proceed with the rest of your code.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I really appreciate your advice and it directs me toward topics I need to learn.

Comment: It's correct to default to `shell=False` as policy, but there are no security implications for `shell=True` when running a literal (hard-coded) command ... am I overlooking something?

Comment: @FMc: you are correct, no immediate risk here, the point is to avoid bad habits and be aware of the possible pitfalls.

Comment: @Anonymous Makes sense, just wanted to confirm that I understood the underlying issue. Good answer, BTW.

Answer (score 5):

#### if **name**=="**main**"

Common practice is to put the code in functions, and to call those functions from `if __name__=="__main__"` block. This will allow your file to be reused as a module, because this block will not be executed in the module.

#### Too many variables? No.

The number of variables itself is not the problem. Their names is a minor problem; maybe `upower_no_whitespaces` or something would be better than `b_join`.

#### Extra processes called

Your code calls two external processes: `upower` and `grep`. It's ok to do so for a one-shot script; but if you will grow this into some monitoring script, consider using something like [upower-python](https://github.com/wogscpar/upower-python) instead of calling upower and/or doing the job of grep inside your program.

#### Twice filtering of whitespaces

I'm pretty sure you've tried to filter out whitespaces of the string; but regex doesn't work this way = it looks for a combination of tab(\t), new line(\n), any whitespace(\s) and any non-word character(\W) in a row together. And after changing this into spaces, you're changing spaces into nothing.

I think it will be much better to split the string by ':', take the part you need and remove whitespaces, if needed, with .strip() method. Or use .split() without arguments - it will split the string by any whitespace or whitespace group.

#### Error handling

Your code lacks any. What will happen if there's no battery on the device? Or if it is called not `/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0`? Or of the format of `upower` output changes?

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time and helping me with my code. Greatly and wholeheartedly appreciated.

Comment: _doing the job of grep inside your program_ - This. `shell=True` needs to go away, and do the grep yourself.